# ubuntu software center and update manager is not working

Tags: apt, adobe-reader

my update manager is not working and showing the message

```
E:The package adobereader-enu:i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling the corresponding package will solves your problem. Try the below command to reinstall the package mentioned in the error report.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall adobereader-enu:i386
```

Answer (score 0):

**Adobe Reader is not available in the Trusty repos currently.** How did you install it to begin with? As that may affect future attempts. You can download the file directly from the Adobe website, but **it doesn't appear to be compatible with 14.04**. I was able to install it, but it wouldn't launch. The steps I used are below should you wish to obtain the package. I would suggest waiting for an updated version to be released.

## Steps:

Step #1

In terminal type `wget ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/unix/9.x/9.5.5/enu/AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i386linux_enu.deb`.

Step #2 (Optional)

In terminal type `sudo apt-get install gdebi`. [You can use whatever package manager you want (eg Ubuntu Software Center), but for ease my instructions use gdebi.]

Step #3

In nautilus browse to the folder you saved the .deb to, right click, and choose open with gdebi. Now click install. You will receive an error regarding adobereader-enu which depends on libgtk2.0-0.

Step #4

In terminal type `sudo apt-get install -f`. You should now have all the required dependencies including libgtk2.0-0. The installation should complete successfully, but Adobe Reader won't launch.

## Notes:

- I tested this on Ubuntu - Desktop X86-64 the results may differ for Ubuntu - Desktop X86-32.
- Even though it won't launch you can tell it's installed because you will have an icon for it in your applications area, and if you type `gksu acroread` in terminal you will get the typical "adobe reader doesn't require sudo" warning.
- Error received when attempting to launch Adobe Reader

`/opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread: error while loading shared libraries: libxml2.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`